# ReactJS - Change Component in parent depending on nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my App wrapped in a component which renders a Header, Footer and any routed child components.

I am trying to replace the `<Header />` component with `</HeaderAdmin/>` when at /admin.

**Routes**

```
<Route path='/' component={SiteWrapper} >
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="admin" component={Admin}>
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
  </Route>      
</Route>
```

**SiteWrapper Comp**

```
export default class SiteWrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/> // Want to replace with <AdminHeader /> if on /admin
                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.children.props.route.header ? <PageHeader header={this.props.children.props.route.header} /> : null}
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this.props.location.pathname` to find the route name

```
export default class SiteWrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {(this.prop.location.pathname === 'admin')? <AdminHeader/>: <Header/>} 
                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.children.props.route.header ? <PageHeader header={this.props.children.props.route.header} /> : null}
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: if we can do this, then why do we even need the <route> from react router

Answer (score 0):

For that, I think you can check the route by `window.location` or `this.props.location.pathname`, it will contain the route names, if the route name is `/admin` then render the `Header` component otherwise `render` the `AdminHeader` component.

Write it like this:

```
{ this.prop.location.pathname === '/admin'? <AdminHeader/>: <Header/>}
```